# Use BQL In Acumatica Web Services API

Tags: acumatica

I was wondering whether there was a way to directly use BQL in order to retrieve data from Acumatica instead of Exporting/Importing/Submitting from the Screen Context? Or are we only restricted to do what each screen allows us to?

Otherwise, is there a simple way I could use the Generic Enquiry screen (SM208000) through the API to retrieve data?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute BQL commands straight from web services; you have access to what each screen provide. Generic inquiries themselves provide a web service, but do not allow arbitrary execution of queries.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way is to create GI and then use it in web services.

Comment: Does that really work? doesn't the GI redirect you to another screen to view the results? how does the web service context deal with this? Could you give me a code sample of how I could do this please?

Answer (score 0):

If your application resides in the same domain as the web server and if you are referencing the PXData, PXcommon, and PXObject dll's that the website uses, you would be able to use BQL, otherwise, Gabriel's answer trumps.